# Merge a ramas diferentes en git

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

espero poder hacerme entender en mi pregunta.

Tengo un proyecto "CMS" el cual lo tengo versionado en bitbucket, en el trabajamos 6 personas las cuales estamos día a día subiendo comits repetidamente.

Lo que sucede es hay veces en las se requiere un cambio fuerte en un archivo pero no sé puede subir a producción "sitio web" ya que primero toca verificar el cambio y posteriormente hay sí subirlo, pero puede llegar un ajuste del mismo archivo en el tiempo en que se hace la verificación del anterior cambio y necesita ser subido urgentemente pero si se sube, se subiría con el ajuste que está en verificación.

La pregunta es, ¿Hay forma de tener una rama que sea "producción" la cual tendra todos los archivos en estado estable, y si hay un cambio que necesesite verificación y al mismo tiempo un cambio urgente de subida, hacer un "merge" a la rama de producción pero solo agregando al archivo el cambio que es urgente de subir y omitiendo el que se necesita verificar, y ps ya que se verifique el anterior cambio, hay sí hacer el merge completo de ese archivo a la rama "producción"?

Agradezco cualquier ayuda o una guía de cómo podría resolver este problema.

Comment: Es un antipatrón tener branches diferentes por ambientes. En su lugar deberías tener un único branch el cual luego de ser compilado y deployando en un ambiente y verificado que funciona puedas redeployar en el sgte ambiente

Comment: Lo anterior no significa que debes tener un único branch en todo el repo, porque igual nuevas funcionalidades o bug fixes deben ser desarrollados en sus propios branches.

Comment: Según entiendo en tu comentario, debería trabajar una rama diferente cada persona y luego hacer el merge a la rama producción? Siendo así, existe alguna manera de traer un archivo de la rama producción, editarlo en mi rama y luego hacer el merge solo de ese archivo a producción?

Comment: Espero te sirva de guia. http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/